# Unable to track page in fake folder

Tags: google-analytics

I have urls like mywebsite.com/something/something which I cannot track.

What I can track is e.g. `www.mywebsite.com/faq`

What I cannot track is e.g. `www.mywebsite.com/myaccount/mycampaigns`

There is no such folder as myaccount, I made that up with .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule    ^faq/?$    faq.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^myaccount/mycampaigns/?$    mycampaigns.php    [NC,L]
```

How to track whether the user got to that page?

[image]

Comment: what would happen when I try the url `myaccount/mycampaign` in a browser ? I would on a page mycampaigns.php ? `RewriteRule` would not change the url ? right ?

Comment: If you type `www.mywebsite.com/myaccount/mycampaigns` the page that actually opens is `www.mywebsite.com/mycampaigns.php` but what you'll see in the browser bar is `www.mywebsite.com/myaccount/mycampaigns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the tracking code to that page. I thought I added it to all pages and still, I missed this one. What an amateur I am.